# How to refresh a nib?

Tags: ios, nib

I need to init my app which is using tab bars. 
I have no problem switch between the tab to initialize tab view. The problem is when I press the home button and start my app again the next day, I want to nib to initialize straight away.

If there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could probably from the app delegate refresh them... If you have a reference to your `UITabBarController` in your app delegate you can do something like this:

```
 [[[[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] refreshData]; //This would call the refreshData in your first tab bar.
```

Comment: Try it and it not working. Some error.  no '-refreshData' method found

Comment: Well, refreshData is a method you should have in your UIViewController to update what you want to be updated...

Comment: Zhacary if this answer helped you, you should accept it, since it will also help you to get more answers in the future. Thanks.